# What is the right way to implement authorization for interservice communication with RBAC?

Tags: authentication, keycloak, rbac

We have some web system:

- frontend client
- keycloak for Oauth2.0 implementation
- 3 backend services

  - OrangeService - is the service to store info about Orange entity
  - AppleService - is the service to store info about Apple entity
  - JuiceService - service for async making juice, lets assume that `make_juice` operation takes about 10 min
- access_token lifetime for example 1 min

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7Wm5.png)

Flow:

- John Doe authenticate in Keycloak and redirect to frontend app
- John Doe opens Apples page. We must show him only his apples. So on AppleService we take his jwt and query Keycloak for UMA permissions, then we make a decision which entities John Doe can see, which entities can change etc.
- Than the same happens for Oranges page.
- Next John Doe comes to Juice page and start long calculation operation. Frontend query to JuiceService. On Juice service we check John's Doe permissions again, and accept his request, so we put task in queue and return task_id.
- For task to be calculated we have to get data in worker from Data Services. So we make requests to Orange and Apple Services. But we need some JWT token in worker for authorized requests. Besides it would be great, that token is somehow connected with John Doe, so we can check access to requested entities in DataServices.
- Definitely we cannot use access token which we received on JuiceService endpoint, because of it lifetime

How this should work in my opinion. JuiceServiceWorker get its own jwt, so on AppleService we can be sure who came to us to get data, and we can get John's Doe actual permissions on AppleService (if we pass permissions from JuiceService, they can be already outdated), and make a decision about access to data.

I feel that there should be a good solution for this, but a lot of google and youtube haven't helped to find a solution. Do anybody know good solution for this, and solution with keycloak as IAM?

There are some solutions, but I nothing good

1. Increase jwt lifetime, awful solution, definitely bad
2. Land authorization on proxy or gateway, and make all services without auth. Not good, decrease security, because we loose inner layer, if attacker get through proxy somehow, then all services will be unprotected
3. Make users in keycloak for backend services. Not good, it makes some mash in keycloak, besides anyway we cannot check John Doe permissions, when request come to DataService from worker.

Answer (score 0):

A useful technique for this type of use-case is to use token exchange from [RFC8693](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8693.html).

**INITIAL TOKEN**

Consider this pseudo token issued to a client, with user level privileges:

```json
{
  "sub": 123,
  "scope": "fruit:write fruit:read",
  "aud": "api.company.com",
  "exp": (15 minutes),
  "role: supervisor",
}
```

**EXCHANGED TOKEN**

The exchanged token has an extended lifetime but reduced privileges:

```json
{
  "sub": 123,
  "scope": "fruit:read",
  "aud": "job.company.com",
  "transaction_id": 8765,
  "exp": (12 hours),
  "role: supervisor",
}
```

The new token will generally `downscope` the original token, or introduce restrictions, but extend its lifetime, eg:

- the new token must be rejected at normal API endpoints, eg because of its audience
- the new token might only valid for a particular transation which the upstream process manages

In scenarios where you are not overriding user consent, it is even possible to `upscope`. Of course, your APIs must enforce such restrictions.

**EMBEDDED TOKENS**

A related approach, which might be possible in some use cases, and which reduces the number of token exchange requests, is to issue such a token at the time of user authentication, then include it as a custom claim in the main token.

**MAINTAINING USER IDENTITIES**

These `token sharing patterns` are ways to keep the user identity, and other important security values, digitally verifiable and auditable, as APIs call each other.

I cannot advise on support for this standard in particular providers though.